# Can't cast a row to a DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, datagridview

I think this is weird and I can't figure out why it's not working.
I have a **DataTable** named **tempDT**

**This is working:** Does this code also cast the rows into a DataGridViewRow?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tempDT.Rows)
{
  //  do iteration       
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
    //  do iteration
  }
}
```

**This too:** If I do it like that, it's only possible to cast it into a DataRow!

```
DataRow row2 = ((DataRow)tempDT.Rows[0]);
```

**But this not:**

```
DataGridViewRow row1 = ((DataGridViewRow)tempDT.Rows[0]);
```

Why do I can't cast it like above?

Comment: plz explain it little more for better understandability

Comment: A row of what ?

Comment: What is the actual type of the row you are trying to cast?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is working for me fine ,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>() { new Customer() { ID = 1, Name = "XYZ" }, new Customer() { ID = 1, Name = "XYZ" } };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;

            DataGridViewRowCollection c =  dataGridView1.Rows;
            DataGridViewRow val = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
            Console.WriteLine(val.Cells[0].Value);
        }

        private class Customer
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Problem with you code is you are trying to convert DataTable row i.e. DataRow to DataGridViewRow . (that is what I think from code you have given). if that is the case than you cannot convert DataRow to DataGridViewRow.